# Can you link static library directly in android application?

Tags: android, c++, static-libraries

I am sorry maybe this is stupid what I am asking,  but I have a question about linking **static/shared** libraries in android.

I am creating a new **C++ Native** android studio project. After build, I open the apk file, and inside `lib` the folder there are placed libraries `libnative-lib.so` for every ABI. Size of **APK** is **3.580 KB**.

But if I change inside `CMakeLists.txt` to build the native lib like **Static** lib, so now I got this:

```
add_library(native-lib
             STATIC
             native-lib.cpp)
```

When APK is built, I can not find the static library (**libnative-lib.a**). There is no `lib` folder in the apk. Also, the size is **2.836 KB**.

Can someone please explain(or give me link for more info about this) where is the library placed in the **STATIC** build?

And on run I got error if I link static:

```
No implementation found for java.lang.String com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.stringFromJNI()
```

Comment: static linkage means sources of static libraries ane linked inside the binary together with other binary's sources

Comment: @user1056837 thanks for comment, but why when its linked static I run app, and I got error `No implementation found for java.lang.String com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.stringFromJNI()` but it is there in native-lib.cpp file.  It looks like it cant find the static lib?

Comment: All I can suggest to you: read about shared and static libraries in unix, e.g. https://www.google.com/search?q=shared+static+libraries+unix I believe this should help you to clarify it a bit.

Comment: I found something that, static libraries can not be linked in android app directly like i tried, but i cant find the source.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you wrote. As I said before - any static library is just a set of object files. If you link it, you just link its object files with your main.o and other object files (if any). Please try to find in documentation this part about jni wrappers of c++ functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use *native* static libraries directly in Android apps.

Android user space is basically a Java (or more precisely [Dalvik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software)) VM).
So all user-facing applications must be written in Java or Kotlin (which both compile to Dalvik bytecode).

Static C/C++ libraries must be link in to a C/C++ executable or dynamic library to be used. They can not be loaded directly by Linux or Android.

Since Android app does not have a C/C++ executable in it, the only way to use a static library with an Android app is to link it with a dynamic library (*.so) that can be loaded via [Java Native Interface](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni).

Since JNI uses the system loader to load the library, it can only load dynamic libraries, and of those, only ones that export functions with proper naming conventions so they can be matched to a Java class that will be used to call the native code.